# Tracking memory leak - bitmaps

Tags: android, image, memory-leaks, bitmap, mat

I have problem with tracking mmemory leak in my app. 
I'm using MAT to do this, but i'm also beginner in this feature so i need your help.

Dominator tree looks like this:
[image]

Obviously 23% for bitmap isn't normal...

Path to GC Root -> exclude weak references:

[image]

But I really don't know what to do next ... It is obvious that memory is leaking through the images.

I'm converting resources to Bitmaps and scale it like this:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromRes(int resId) {
    Bitmap tmp = null;
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        // Decode image size
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        int scale = 1;

        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        InputStream fis = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (tmp != null) {
            tmp.recycle();
            tmp = null;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Thanks for help and sorry for my english...

Comment: did you use **android:largeHeap="true"** in your manifest file

Comment: no i'm not... obviously

Comment: I'm not sure that is good idea.. In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) Wise man warns against the use of... I belive him :)